# Python - using regex to search for a string then append each match to a new list

Tags: python, cad, step

I am currently trying to extract some data from a file which has this kind of format:

```
#12 = ADVANCED_FACE ( 'NONE', ( #194 ), #326, .F. ) ;
...
#159 = EDGE_LOOP ( 'NONE', ( #21, #124, #264, #145 ) ) ;
...
#194 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE', #159, .T. ) ;
...
#326 = PLANE ( 'NONE',  #352 ) ;
```

The following is the method I am currently using:

```
faces_txt = re.findall(r'#(\d+) = ADVANCED_FACE.*;', text)

    faces = [int(face) for face in faces_txt]
    print('Face IDs = ', faces)
```

Which outputs:

```
Face IDs =  [12, 73, 99, 131, 181, 214, 244, 273, 330, 358]
```

What would I do if I wanted to create a **new** list (named sequentially like "Face1, Face2, Face3...") for each match of the "ADVANCED_FACE" rather than appending all of these values to the same list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having more details on exact output you want and maybe some more input, it sounds like you want a list of lists or a dictionary of lists.

```
faces_txt = re.findall(r'#(\d+) = ADVANCED_FACE.*;', text)
faces = [int(face) for face in faces_txt]

print('Face IDs = ', faces)

LoL = []
DoL = {}
for i, faceId in enumerate(faces):
    LoL.append([faceId])
    DoL.update({"Face{}".format(i): [faceId]})

print(LoL)
print(DoL)

print(DoL['Face0'])
```